# Estimate on average with weight

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $B_{2R}=B(x,2R)$ be the ball of radius $2R$ centered at $x$ and $v=log\,u$ for some positive function $u$ defined on $B_{2R}$. Denote by $v_{B_{2R}}=\frac{1}{w(B_{2R})}\int_{B_{2R}}v(x)w(x)\,dx$, where $w(B_{2R})=\int_{B_{2R}}w(x)\,dx$.
Then 
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{w(B_{2R})}\int_{B_{2R}}e^{-p_0 v}w(x)\,dx\cdot\frac{1}{w(B_{2R})}\int_{B_{2R}}e^{p_0 v}w(x)\,dx\\
=\frac{1}{w(B_{2R})}\int_{B_{2R}}e^{(p_0 v-p_0 v_{B_{2R}})}w(x)\,dx\cdot\frac{1}{w(B_{2R})}\int_{B_{2R}}e^{(p_0 v_{B_{2R}}-p_0 v)}w(x)\,dx
\end{align*}
Can you kindly help me how to get the above equality.
Thanking you.

Comment: There is just an equality. Is the question missing something?

Comment: No the question is fine. But I am not getting how to prove. Can you please explain. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what the question is. Prove what? why the two sides are equal, post multiplying and dividing by a constant? I don't know if I'm missing something.

Comment: I want to prove the above equality which looks trivial to you. If you kindly explain your argument more clearly, it will be very grateful for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's multiplication by $e^{\alpha-\alpha}$, where $\alpha$ is the product above.

Comment: which product, is it the RHS or LHS product?

Comment: It would be better, if you can write the proof.

Comment: Can you kindly have a look at the following question in the link:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3057107/integration-over-a-ball-of-power-of-mod-function?noredirect=1#comment6303161_3057107