# Property of supremum for any real exponent

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

For any $\alpha>0$ and $f:\Omega\to(0,\infty)$ bounded, is it true that $\sup f^{\alpha}\leq (\sup f)^\alpha$?

Also what about $\alpha<0$.

I know for $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$, it holds.

But for any $\alpha>0$, unable to prove or give counter-example.

Please help me.

Comment: I have edited the question. Sorry to make you confuse.

Comment: This just follows from $f(x) \le \sup f$ for a.a. $x \in \Omega$.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I should have done it by own. Thank you for opening my eyes.

Comment: Can you kindly have a look at the following question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2996709/estimate-on-average-with-weight?noredirect=1#comment6182539_2996709