# Integration over a ball of power of mod function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

Let $B(0,r)$ be a ball of radius $r$ with centre $0$ and $B(x_0,r)$ be a ball of radius $r$ with centre $x_0$. Let $w:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $w(x)=|x|^{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. Then how to calculate the following integral:
$$
\int_{B(x_0,r)}w(x)\,dx
$$

I am trying to use the change of variable by substituting $x-x_0=z$, then $z\in B(0,r)$. Therefore we obtain
$$
\int_{B(x_0,r)}w(x)\,dx=\int_{B(x_0,r)}|x|^{\alpha}\,dx=\int_{B(0,r)}|z+x_0|^\alpha\,dz.
$$
Can you help me from here how to proceed?

Thank you very much.

Comment: [Check this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates)

Comment: Sorry, I did not get something fruitful. Can you kindly help getting the exact integral in my direction.

Comment: I cant find a reference at the moment, but I recall the integration formula over a ball to be $\int_{B(0,r)}f(x)dx=\int_0^r (\int_{\partial B(0,y)}f(x)y^{(n-1)}dS(x)) dy$. Please double check it though!

Comment: In Evans book this formula is given. But I want a formula for center $x_0\neq 0$.  Thank you.